# Why Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors() does not work when I pass the history object (which is part of the BOM) to it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

There are different objects in the browser object model (BOM) such as history, location, document, etc. I can get the property descriptors for the location and the document objects but not for the history object. Why is that so?

[image]

Comment: `location` is rather unusual in that its method are not part of the `Location.prototype` object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the history object instance has no "own" properties. All of them are inherited from its prototype, which by definition are not included in `Object.getOwn[anything]` functions. You will also notice that `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(history)` is an empty array when you run it, telling us as much.

(Unlike [location](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#the-location-interface) or [document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-document-object), which are objects with `defineOwnProperty` steps as part of their formal instantiation specification, [history](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#history) is an "empty" object with fairly special handling, but following [the normal rules for object instantiation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new))

Instead, use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Object.getPrototypeOf(history))` if you want to see its "immediate" API.

Comment: "*The Location exotic object is defined through a mishmash of IDL, invocation of JavaScript internal methods post-creation, and overridden JavaScript internal methods. Coupled with its scary security policy, please take extra care while implementing this excrescence.*" - oh wow. I'd say that `history` is a rather "normal" object with *less* special handling. Unlike the other two you mention, it does not have `[LegacyOverrideBuiltIns]` or `[LegacyUnforgeable]` attributes.

Comment: Honestly, they're both weird =D (although `history` more for how it actually works rather than how it gets constructed)